# Upgrade path - Oracle Standard to Oracle Enterprise

Tags: oracle

Could I start on Oracle Standard edition and easily upgrade to Oracle Enterprise?

Or do I need to rebuild the entire server? how does the upgrade path work?

Comment: From my research, It seems like you have to uninstall standard edition, then reinstall enterprise edition in order to upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

It's easy because internal database structure almost identical:

1. Backup all database files and /network/admin (just for sure);
2. Uninstall Standard Edition;
3. Install Enterprise Edition;
4. Point ORACLE_SID to old database;
5. Startup database and run `catalog.sql` and `catproc.sql` from new version;
6. Recompile all invalid objects.

Note that software version, release number and patch level must be identical.

Comment: 0. Shutdown the standard edition instance cleanly?

Comment: @DavidAldridge Yes, this step is necessary too. But answer provided to demonstrate level of complexity rather than give detailed instructions.  For more detailed instruction you must look to oracle documentation, e.g. `"How to Convert Database from Standard to Enterprise Edition ? [ID 117048.1]"` article on MyOracleSupport (former Metalink).